# Why does handedness suggest that the brain is asymmetrical?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, brain

From The Human Mind, by Paul Bloom:

> If you just look at a brain - if you remove it from somebody's head and put it on the table - it looks symmetrical. But it isn't. The asymmetry of the brain is manifested in handedness. Some people are right-handed, and others are left-handed, and since motor control comes from the brain, this suggests that the brain itself is asymmetrical. It has a right side and a left side, and they are not identical.

(In this case, I am taking him to mean functionally asymmetrical.)

Of course I'm not disputing that the brain is indeed asymmetrical, but I'm struggling to understand how he draws this conclusion based on the flow of logic above. i.e.

1.) Almost all people have a preferential side for motor control.

2.) Motor control comes from the brain.

3.) Ergo, the brain itself is likely asymmetrical.

How do we get from 1. & 2. to 3.? Playing the devil's advocate here: could a response to the above not be that left handed people have a more active right hemisphere (with respect to motor control), but that the hemispheres are functionally identical? This is obviously an incorrect conclusion, but could it be shown to be incorrect only using the arguments outlined above?

Comment: If they were identical, why would there be a preferred hand? Where would the preference come from, physically?